# Why do I get a strange value when decreasing a WORD type counter in MASM Assembly?

Tags: loops, assembly, masm32

I'm working on some code in MASM Assembly using Kip Irvine libraries. I have some code like this:

```
mov eax, n_var
mov icount, eax
mov ecx,0

.WHILE icount >= ecx

mov esi, icount
fld vector_sol[esi * 8]

dec icount
.ENDW
```

The problem is that when icount is 0, then in the next loop icount should be -1, but instead, it gets the value of 4294967295. The same happens if I try to loop with a register instead of icount.

Comment: That's normal if you print it as unsigned. Use signed output. You didn't show how you print, though.

Comment: Also no idea what the `>=` operator uses. You should refrain from these helper things (e.g. the `.WHILE`) especially if you are a beginner. Just code pure asm.

Comment: Indeed, `-1` encodes as `FFFFFFFFh`, and `4294967295` also encodes as `FFFFFFFFh`. The difference is in their *context*.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> mov ecx,0
> .WHILE icount >= ecx
> ```

In an unsigned context this will **always be true** (Every value is above or equal to zero) and so an endless loop is the result.

Before using the `.WHILE` and `.ENDW` directives you should understand how they operate. From the MASM manual we learn:

> These constructs work much as they do in a high-level language such as C or
>   Pascal. Keep in mind the following points:
>
> - These directives generate appropriate processor instructions. They are not new instructions.
> - They require proper use of signed and unsigned data declarations.
>
> These directives cause a set of instructions to execute based on the evaluation of some condition. This condition can be an expression that evaluates to a **signed** or **unsigned** value, an expression using the binary operators in C (&&, ||, or !), or the state of a flag. For more information about expression operators, see page 178.
>   The evaluation of the condition requires the assembler to know if the operands
>   in the condition are signed or unsigned. To state explicitly that a named memory
>   location contains a signed integer, use the signed data allocation directives
>   SBYTE, SWORD, and SDWORD.

So in short your *icount* variable should have been declared as a SDWORD, because then when `dec icount` brings the value down to -1 the while condition will no longer be true, thus exiting the loop.